# SAS and proc sql

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I have to get rid of a subject if it satisfies a condition.

DATA:

```
Name Value1 
A      60
A      30
B      70
B      30
C      60
C      50
D      70
D      40
```

What I want is if the value=30 then both the lines should not come in theoutput.

Desired outpu is

```
Name Value1 
C      60
C      50
D      70
D      40
```

I have written a code in proc sql as

```
proc sql;
  create table ck1 as
  select * from ip where name in
     (select distinct name from ip where value = 30)
     order by name, subject, folderseq;
quit;
```

Comment: so what's the question?

Answer (score 3):

Change your SQL to be:

```
proc sql;
  create table ck1 as
  select * from ip where name not in
     (select distinct name from ip where value = 30)
     order by name, subject, folderseq;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Data step method:

```
data have;
input Name $ Value1;
datalines;
A      60
A      30
B      70
B      30
C      60
C      50
D      70
D      40
;;;;
run;
data want;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
  set have;
  by name;
  if value1=30 then value1_30=1;
  if value1_30=1 then leave;
end;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
    set have;
    by name;
    if value1_30 ne 1 then output;
end;
run;
```

And an alternate, slightly faster method in some cases that avoids the second set statement when value1_30 is 1 (this is faster in particular if most have a 30 in them, so you're only keeping a small number of records).

```
data want;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
  set have;
  by name;
  counter+1;
  if first.name then firstcounter=counter;
  else if last.name then lastcounter=counter;
  if value1=30 then value1_30=1;
  if value1_30=1 then leave;
end;
if value1_30 ne 1 then
  do _n_ = firstcounter to lastcounter ;
    set have point=_n_;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another SQL option...

```
proc sql number; 
select 
a.name, 
a.value1, 
case
when value1 = 30 then 1
                 else 0
end as flag,
sum(calculated flag) as countflagpername
from have a
group by a.name
having countflagpername = 0
;quit;
```